# Angular 2/Jasmine, updating an activated route params subscription within each describe/it block

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-testing

Given a simple component that subscribes to the activated route query params in `ngOnInit`:

```
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  private queryParams: any;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => this.queryParams = params);
  }

  active(foo: number): boolean {
    return this.queryParams['foo'] &&
      foo === +this.queryParams['foo'];
  }
}
```

The active function should return true when the `foo` query param is present and its value matches the supplied parameter.

In the accompanying unit tests for this component, I want to change the value of the query params within each `it` block to test the query param not being present, matching the parameter and not matching the parameter.

```
describe('FooComponent', () => {
  let component: FooComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>;
  let activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute;

  class MockActivatedRoute {
    queryParams = Observable.of({});
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FooComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    activatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
  });

  describe('active', () => {
    it('should return false if the foo query param is not present', () => {
      activatedRoute.queryParams = Observable.of({});
      let result = component.active(100);
      expect(result).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should return false if the foo query param does not match the supplied parameter', () => {
      activatedRoute.queryParams = Observable.of({ foo: '500' });
      let result = component.active(100);
      expect(result).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should return true if the foo query param does not match the supplied parameter', () => {
      activatedRoute.queryParams = Observable.of({ foo: '500' });
      let result = component.active(500);
      expect(result).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});
```

Rather the value of the private queryParams member of the FooComponent class does not update within each `it` block. I've tried the various methods of `async`, `fixture.whenStable()`, and `fakeAsync/tick`.

How do I update the value of the subscription for each unit test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are assigning a new Observable, but the client is already subscribed to the first Observable. This happens because `ngOnInit` is called when you first call `fixture.detectChanges()`. If you waited to called `fixture.detectChanges()` *after* you assign the new Observable to the queryParams, then that Observable would be used.

Another option (maybe preferred) is to instead of using an Observable, you can use a `Subject`. With this, you can control when data is emitted, and what to emit.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import { fakeAsync, tick } from

class MockActivatedRoute {
  queryParams = new Subject<any>();
}

let route: MockActivatedRoute;

beforeEach(() => {
  /* configure */ 

  route = <MockActivatedRoute>TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
})

it('', fakeAsync(() => {
  route.queryParams.next(newparams);    // emit something
  tick();                               // wait for resolution
  fixture.detectChanges();              // detect changes (for ui)
  expect(...)
}))
```

I say this options might be preferred as it allows for emitting multiple values in the same test.